# aspx page missing sections, validation not working

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sharepoint, webforms

I am trying to diagnose an issue where `RequiredFieldValidators` are not firing in certain environments and I narrowed the problem down to the fact that the `Page_Validators` array was not being set for the sites where it didn't work.

I looked into it and the validator array variable is set in the `//<[!CDATA[ ... //]]>` section.  Because I don't set this directly, I assume this was .NET doing its work.  However, I noticed that the section of code responsible for setting this variable is missing in certain pages, causing the issue.  In fact, the entire file is different, with the broken version missing about half of the markup.  The code is broken into pieces, there are large (> 200 line) sections of white space, and the markup is not formatted nearly as well.

What could the problem be?  There is no difference to the code that is deployed to either environment, but I am seeing this in a few places.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So I tried again...this time the full page was generated but the CDATA section is not color-formatted in Chrome's debugger.  Not sure if this is important, but it's also missing a </head> tag.  Maybe its related to formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what it was, it is a bit silly but glad it wasn't too complicated.  One of our master pages had a script tag that wasn't properly closed.  Once that was fixed, the code executed as expected.